# Is Business entities/objects about organizing or performance optimizing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, architecture, webforms

I don't know the difference between `Business Entities` and `Business Objects`

But what I have is a class that has some properties and I'll add an IsValid method later.

That's what Application Architecture Tutorials taught me

But it just hit me, ***what's the difference*** between using this approach and just sending/receiving my data through my layers without storing them in objects .. and when I add an item to the database, instead of creating an object of the item's type then store it and send it to the BLL or the DAL, I would just send the information I just collected as it is, as an argument to my BLL methods!

I'm sorry if my question is a bit confusing. But I hope that you'll excuse me as this question and the application architecture is a just a very big ocean ..And I'm LOST! =S

P.S: I added the technologies I'm using, Hoping it will help you understand my environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that either way can work--it's possible to pass your data around as a series of parameters and make it work.  There are even situations where it might be more derirable to do it that way (e.g. a **really** simple application).

That said, it's generally accepted that it's easier to code and maintain an object or set of objects that represent your data than it is to pass multiple (possibly many) parameters through every method call and layer of your application.

This concept is called *encapsulation*, and is one of the core principles of Object Oriented Programming.  A quick google will probably answer your question more completely.

Comment: . Thanks for the brief, but I wanna know if the BO/BE helps in performance or in organizing my code!

Comment: It's easier to code and maintain as I said, so: yes, it helps in organizing your code.  I would say no, it doesn't help with performance directly.  By having code that is easier to maintain, it will be easier to isolate code that doesn't perform well and optimize it.

Comment: . Well, I guess there's no perfect answer for my question but things are clearer now. If you have an article or a book that go through this topic that would be great .. Thanks and sorry for my late reply.